# How do I change the destination directory of Ant's fileset command?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, ant, jar

I have an Ant buildfile for a Java library. It looks something like this:

```xml
<project ... ><target ... >
<jar destfile="C:\path\to\export.jar">
    <manifest> ... </manifest>
    <fileset dir="C:\path\to\bin" />
    <fileset dir="C:\path\to\src" />
    <fileset dir="C:\path\to\doc" />
    <zipfileset src="C:\path\to\included\library.jar" />
</jar>
</target></project>
```

The only problem is that my JavaDoc is being exported directly into the root directory of the resulting jar file. Essentialy, I'd like some equivalent of the `<copydir>` command that can be used inside the `<jar>` command.

My desired structure is this:

```
export.jar
  META-INF
    Manifest.MF
  com
    example
      whatever
        Blah.class
        Blah.java
  org
    external
      somelibrary
        Magic.class     // contents of the included library jar file
  doc
    // javadoc files here
```

The current structure is:

```
export.jar
  META-INF
    Manifest.MF
  com
    example
      whatever
        Blah.class
        Blah.java
        // some javadoc files here
  org
    external
      somelibrary
        Magic.class     // contents of the included library jar file
  // more javadoc files here
```

---

My current "solution" is to omit the documentation `<fileset>` command, then, once the jar has exported, go into Windows Explorer and **right click** → **7-Zip** → **Open Archive**; I can then drop the `doc` directory in there just fine. However, this pretty completely defeats the purpose of Ant as a completely automated build system.

If it matters, this file was originally generated by Eclipse with the Runnable JAR exporter. However, I obviously need to modify it to add source files, etc. because it's a library and not actually a runnable jar. I exported it as a runnable jar to get Eclipse to package in the required libraries; apparently libraries on the build path aren't available for export via the standard **File** → **Export** → **JAR file**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A jar is actually like a zip file. Hence you can use a `zipfileset`. Its attribute `prefix` is what you are looking for.

The `zipfileset` command can accept either a zip file via `src` or a filesystem directory via `dir`. Using the latter, you can add the following command:

```
<zipfileset dir="C:\path\to\doc" prefix="doc" />
```

Also worth to note is that zipfileset supports all attributes of fileset. Thus if you want to include just a single file in a specific location you can use:

```
<zipfileset file="C:\path\to\doc\file.txt" prefix="doc" />
```

Further reading: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html

Comment: I'm aware that a jar uses zip compression. However, my `doc` folder is not a zip file, just a folder. according to Eclipse, there is no attribute `prefix` on the `fileset` command.

Comment: `zipfileset` can be used in two ways. One as a fileset within a zip file. One as a fileset to be included in a zip (or a jar, this is the same). The last one is for your use case. Read the first lines of the doc I have pointed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind I'll edit your answer to include a code sample.